# Querying in solr

Tags: solr, facet, solrj

I have the following query which I took from my URL

```
public static String query="pen&mq=pen&f=owners%5B%22abc%22%5D&f=application_type%5B%22cde%22%5D";
```

I want to query solr using this query

```
 CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer( "http://localhost:8080/solr/");          
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());          
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery(query); 
 QueryResponse qr =server.query(solrQuery);
 SolrDocumentList sdl = qr.getResults();

System.out.println("Found: " + sdl.getNumFound());
```

I checked my query in tomcat logs file and it is translated as

```
path=/select params={version=2&wt=javabin&q=pen%26mq%3Dpen%26f%3Downers%255B%2522abc%2522%255D%26f%3Dapplication_type%255B%2522cde%2522%255D`
```

and it is giving me 0 result inspite of having 500 docs.
I tried to decode my query using

```
URLDecoder.decode(query,"UTF-8");
```

but then it started complaining about "[" signs.

```
org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Encountered " "]" "]
```

How should i query solr server using this query?
Is it necessary to parse the query and take the value of each filter and then use

```
 solrQuery.setFilterQueries()
```

method. Can somebody please help me in that

Answer (score 3):

If you compare what you took from the url in your manual call to Solr and what is being passed as parameters to the solr call from Solrj according to the tomcat logs, they do not match up.

Looks like you are passing encoded url parameters in your call: `solrQuery.setQuery(query)` and then Solrj is applying encoding to those already encoded parameters. You can see this where `pen&mq=pen`is being turned itnto `q=pen%26mq%3Dpen`

Based on the [Solrj Wiki Page](http://wiki.apache.org/sole/Solrj) I would suggest setting all of your query parameters using the `query.setParam` option. So you would need to do the following:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery("pen");
solrQuery.setParam("mq","pen");
solrQuery.setParam("f","owners[\"abc\"]");
solrQuery.setParam("f","application_type[\"cde"\]");
QueryResponse qr = server.query(solrQuery);
SolrDocumentList sdl = qr.getResults();

System.out.println("Found: " + sdl.getNumFound());
```

**Update:** Added complete conversion to setParams.

Comment: so is it necessary for me to parse the query string which i took from url

Comment: In the case of using the SolrJ, yes. You cannot just take a straight URL that you built from (I am assuming) the Solr Admin page and paste it into SolrJ as the query. You need to build the same parameters using the SolrJ methods. I will my answer to accomodate for all of your parameters in the question.